# where is WSASocket defined?

Tags: c, winapi, winsock2

I am trying to dynamically link winsock functions starting with `WSASocket`, the following code compile just fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef SOCKET (WINAPI * pWSASocket)(int, int, int, LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOA, GROUP, DWORD);

int main()
{
        HMODULE hmod = LoadLibrary("ws2_32.dll");
        if (hmod == NULL)
        {
                printf("Failed to load ws2_32.dll\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        pWSASocket WSASocket = (pWSASocket)GetProcAddress(hmod, "WSASocket");
        if (WSASocket == NULL)
        {
                printf("Failed to find function WSASocket\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

but when running the binary I get the error
`Failed to find function WSASocket`

According the WINAPI docs [WSASocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasocketa) should be in `Ws2_32.dll` but the `GetProcAddress` returns a `NULL` value

Comment: The function is called `WSASocketA`, `WSASocket` is just a macro

Comment: also instead `typedef .. pWSASocket ..` use `EXTERN_C PVOID __imp_WSASocketW = 0;` global variable. `__imp_WSASocketW = GetProcAddress(hmod, "WSASocketW");` and call api as usual `WSASocketW(..)`. in case *x86* need `#pragma warning(disable: 4483)` and `#define __imp_WSASocketW __identifier("_imp__WSASocketW@24")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WSASocket` is a preprocessor symbol declared in *WinSock2.h*, not the name of an exported symbol. The symbols exported by *ws2_32.dll* are named `WSASocketA` or `WSASocketW`.

Since your function pointer declaration uses `LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOA`, you'll probably want to resolve `WSASocketA`. If you were to use [load-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking) instead, this would produce a deprecation warning.

If that is something you care about, link to the `WSASocketW` symbol instead and use `LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW` in the function pointer declaration.